# How do I keep two pieces of information in a LinkedList node?

Tags: java, eclipse, list, linked-list, computer-science

As per requested by my instructor, we were asked to write a Surgery Room booking program as an assignment. He gave us the following breakdown:

A hospital contains a list (**LinkedList**) of rooms.

Each room contains a name (I set mine as a room number **int**) and a list (**LinkedList**) of bookings.

Each list (**LinkedList**) of bookings contains a start and end time (I set mines as **Date**) and a team (another **LinkedList**).

I've set my GUI and I have an idea of how to construct the methods, I'm just finding it difficult to start since I cannot place two pieces of information in one node (like, putting a name and a list of bookings for a particular room).

If it helps, I have a fully implemented:

```
LinkedList<T>  extends AbstractSequentialList<T>  implements List<T>, Deque<T>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

He gave us most of the code, but although it is mostly complete I'm still a little clueless.

Does anyone have any insight on how to deal with the LinkedList issue? Thanks!

Comment: You need to try and then post your code with a specific problem.

Comment: Are you sure that your instructor *really* asked you to implement a new `LinkedList` class?   There is an existing class `java.util.LinkedList`.  Do you think he was actually referring to that?

Comment: Yeah, we had to implement it ourselves as practice, recursively. But that's not even where I am having trouble. It's just sorting the model that he gave us.

Comment: I'm currently attempting the answer given below, it seems to be going alright - I'll get back to you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Create a POJO, a class with two fields, and make your `LinkedList` of that POJO type. For example,

```
public class Room {
    private final int number;
    private final List<Bookings> bookings = new LinkedList<>();

    public Room(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public List<Bookings> getBookings() {
        return bookings;
    }
}
```

And then, you can have a

```
List<Room> rooms = new LinkedList<>();
```

Above, creating `Bookings` with `start` and `end` `Date`s left as an exercise for the reader.